# Rebind windows key of microsoft sculpt ergo mouse

Tags: linux, mouse, xmodmap

I'm trying to rebind the windows key of the microsoft sculpt ergo mouse under linux to backward navigatiom.

Some rebinding works using

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 134 = Backslash"
```

but rebinding to backwards navigation using

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 134 = Mode_switch Alt_R Right" 
xmodmap -e "keycode 134 = Alt_R Right"
```

doesn't work. The former does nothing on a click and the latter seems to press the alt key.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following solution [here](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Xmodmap/)

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 134 = XF86Forward"
xmodmap -e "keycode 134 = XF86Back"
```

You can get the keycode using the tool `xev`